How do I check if a user input contains anything from a list?
I've just made a small quiz. The last question can accept a typed answer from the user, and just needs to include an element of a list to be seen as correct or not correct
    five_ans = input ("What is the answer?")

    list_q5_mark1 = ["answercondition1", "another way to write answercondition1"]
    list_q5_mark2 = ["answercondition2", "another way to write answercondition2"] #the 'another way to write' is just to ensure the user doesn't get an false incorrect. It's the same thing, without spaces.

    if list_q5_mark1 in five_ans:
        print ("correct! it was also answercondition2")
    elif list_q5_mark2 in five_ans:
        print ("correct! it was also answercondition1")
    elif list_q5_mark1 and list_q5_mark2 in five_ans:
        print ("correct! you got both")
    else:
        print ("incorrect")

I want to make it so that the user can input anything, and aslong as it includes one thing from the list, it will be correct. so, they can put 'the answer is 'answercondition1'' and it would give the first print statement, for example.
This is the only way I can think to do this efficiently. When I run this, however, it asks the question, but any answer gives this error:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list


Swap the variables: if five_ans in list_q5_mark1. That's what the error message is telling you, isn't it?

Thanks for the reply =] I've tried this, but then it won't let the user input anything else. Like if they put 'the answer is 'answer' or 'it is 'answer'' it'll be marked as incorrect. I want python to check the users answer for a single word/phrase. Maybe it's just not possible?

So you want to split the user's answer into words, and then check if any of those words are present in the answer list?

Yeah I think maybe that would work?

if any(word in list_q5_mark1 for word in five_ans.split()):

Corrected version of your code:
five_ans = input("What is the answer? ")

list_q5_mark1 = ["answercondition1", "another way to write answercondition1", "bothmarkcode"]
list_q5_mark2 = ["answercondition2", "another way to write answercondition2", "bothmarkcode"]

if five_ans in list_q5_mark1 and five_ans in list_q5_mark2:
    print("correct! you got both")
elif five_ans in list_q5_mark1:
    print("correct! it was also answercondition2")
elif five_ans in list_q5_mark2:
    print("correct! it was also answercondition1")
else:
    print("incorrect")

You just needed to swap the positions of the answer and the list. A quick example to learn:
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

if "banana" in fruits:
  print("yes")

The keyword "in" works in the following way:  element in your_list
Since you saw only one question in your code, I did not change, but you can comment on this answer to ask for the futher help)
